# MIPS Assembly code explanation

Tags: assembly, mips

I have an assignement where we are given the following code in mips assembly and we are asked what the program does. If I follow the program line by line I understand completely each of the commands. What I don't understand is what the program does overall.

```
main:

addi $9, $0, 27
addi $10, $0, 5
addi $2, $0, 1

L1:

and $4, $9, $2
syscall
srl $9, $9, 1
addi $10, $10, -1
bne $10, $0, L1
```

Comment: If you put a comment after each instruction that says what each of them does it should become obvious what the program is doing, assuming that you understand what [bitwise operations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation) do (read up on that if you don't).

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I've already done that (the comments after each instruction is a prerequisite of the assignment) and I do understand bitwise operations but still I don't understand the true function of the program. I know I'm missing something obvious but I'm stuck

Comment: _"but I'm stuck"_. Then run the code in a MIPS simulator like SPIM or MARS.

Comment: OK I finally got it. I'm already using Qtspim and the solution was in front of my eyes. Anyway! Thank you Michael for the responses :D